# Spark Join optimization

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

let's say I have two dataframes that I want to join using "**inner join**": A and B, each one has 100 columns and billions of rows.

If in my use case I'm only interested in 10 columns of A and 4 columns of B, does Spark do the optimization for me in order to handle this and shuffle only 14 columns or will he be shuffling everything then selecting 14 columns?

Query 1 :

```
A_select = A.select("{10 columns}").as("A")
B_select = B.select("{4 columns}").as("B")
result = A_select.join(B_select, $"A.id"==$"B.id")
```

Query 2 :

```
A.join(B, $"A.id"==$"B.id").select("{14 columns}")
```

Is Query1==Query2 in termes of behavior, execution time, data shuffling ?

Thanks in advance for your answers :

Answer (score 1):

Yes, spark will handle the optimization for you. Due to it's lazy evaluation behaviour only the required attributes will be selected from the datafrmes (A and B).

You can use `explain` function to view logical/physical plan,

```
result.explain()
```

Both the query will be returning same physical plan. Hence execution time and data shuffling will be same.

Reference - [Pyspark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) for explain function.